# Backquote Used in Scala Swing Event

Tags: events, swing, scala

I am new to Scala and following one of the examples to get Swing working in Scala and I hava a question. Based on,

```
   listenTo(celsius, fahrenheit)
   reactions += {
      case EditDone(`fahrenheit`) =>
        val f = Integer.parseInt(fahrenheit.text)
        celsius.text = ((f - 32) * 5 / 9).toString

      case EditDone(`celsius`) =>
        val c = Integer.parseInt(celsius.text)
        fahrenheit.text = ((c * 9) / 5 + 32).toString
    }
```

why do I have to use backquote (`) in EditDone(`fahrenheit`) and EditDone(`celsius`) to identify my textfield components e.g. `fahrenheit` and `celsius`? Why can't I just use `EditDone(fahrenheit)` instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has to do with pattern matching. If you use a lower-case name within a pattern match:

```
reactions += {
  case EditDone(fahrenheit) => // ...
}
```

then the object being matched (the event in this case) will be matched against any `EditDone` event on any widget. It will bind the reference to the widget to the name `fahrenheit`. The `fahrenheit` becomes a new value in the scope of that case.

However, if you use backticks:

```
val fahrenheit = new TextField
...
reactions += {
  case EditDone(`fahrenheit`) => // ...
}
```

then the pattern match will only succeed if the `EditDone` event refers to the existing object referenced by the value `fahrenheit`, defined previously.

Note that if the name of the value `fahrenheit` were uppercase, like `Fahrenheit`, then you wouldn't have to use backticks - it would be as if you've put them. This is useful if you have constants or objects in scope that you want to match against - these usually have uppercase names.

Answer (score 8):

```
case EditDone(`fahrenheit`)
```

extracts a value from EditDone and compares it to the existing local variable `fahrenheit`, while

```
case EditDone(fahrenheit)
```

extracts a value from EditDone, creates a new local variable `fahrenheit` (thereby shadowing the existing one) and assigns the extracted value to the new variable.