# match with string numbers - unreachable code

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

New to scala, and can't seem to get my match expression to work. I've read about the differences between how the statement is evaluated (e.g. a new variable as opposed to one declared), but can't seem to get backticks or capitalization to work.

```
// declared inside of object
val numberOne = "+17201234567"
val numberTwo = "+17201235678"

def returnSomething(number: String): String = number match {
  case numberOne => "my first number"
  case numberTwo => "my second number"
  case _ => "a default number"
}

...

returnSomething("+17201235678") // should return "my second number"
```

Please help clarify why this isn't working, as I get an "unreachable code" error at the second line of the match statement. I know this question is all over, but for some reason none of the examples I've seen work for me. Typical noob language stuff. Thanks!

Comment: A possible duplicate - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564220/backquote-used-in-scala-swing-event/6564295#6564295

Comment: Not quite. That question references a match statement using another function on the left-hand side + a back-ticked var which is passed to it. I tried back-ticking numberOne/numberTwo vars with no avail.

Comment: @axel22 See here for possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10863067/406435 . But it is almost impossible to find that question.

Answer (score 7):

Either of these would work:

```
// declared inside of object
val numberOne = "+17201234567"
val numberTwo = "+17201235678"

def returnSomething(number: String): String = number match {
  case `numberOne` => "my first number"
  case `numberTwo` => "my second number"
  case _ => "a default number"
}


// declared inside of object
val NumberOne = "+17201234567"
val NumberTwo = "+17201235678"

def returnSomething(number: String): String = number match {
  case NumberOne => "my first number"
  case NumberTwo => "my second number"
  case _ => "a default number"
}
```

But you said you tried and it did not work. So, what exactly went wrong?